# How do I create a border with gradiant opacity in CSS ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Is it possible to have a border where the inside is of opacity 1 and the outside is of opacity 0 ?

Im wondering this as i have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/4/

I want to be able to drag the rectangle over the axis and see it disappear gradually.

I have found this link : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

But this isn't a gradient from centre to the outside but rather top to bottom :

```
.box{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using radial-gradient for border-image?

Comment: no but ill try it right now thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use box shadow to imitate the border.

something like:

```
.box2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px 4px #3acfd5,0px 0px 0px 20px #3a4ed5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3z3q933/